# Stuck Parsing nested JSON Array

Tags: java, android, json

I'm stuck parsing a nested JSON Array. This should be fairly simple but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a JSON Array like below:

```
    {"currentPage":0,
      "totalPages":1,
      "totalSize":1,
      "first":true,
      "last":true,
      "list"[{"date":"2018-11-07T09:34:25.042+0000",
      "lastUpdated":"2018-11-07T09:34:25.266+0000",
      "id"130674,
      "active":true,
      "address":null,
      "storeMobileNumbers": 
      [{"id":130676,"mobile":"+201008005090","version":0
      }]
  }]
}
```

I'm trying to get the address from the list first, then get the values from storeMobileNumbers.

I have a POJO class for the list, and now I have created a POJO class for the StoreMobileNumbers.

This is what I have right now:

```
      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<MyStore>>(){}.getType();
    Type collection2 = new TypeToken<List<StoreMobileNumber>>({}.getType();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
       if (obj.has("list")) {
         String myList = obj.get("list").toString();
         list1 = gson.fromJson(myList, collectionType);

         JSONArray obj1 = new JSONArray(list1);
         JSONObject numbersObject = obj1.toJSONObject(obj1);
         String mobileList = 
            numbersObject.get("storeMobileNumbers").toString();
            mobileNumbers = gson.fromJson(mobileList, collection2);
        }
```

My StoreMobileNumbersClass:

```
   public class StoreMobileNumber{

   public Long id;
   public String mobile;

   }
```

So far, my efforts have been unsuccessful. I'm getting the following error:

```
   org.json.JSONException: No value for storeMobileNumbers
```

Can someone help me see what I'm missing here?

Comment: incorrect json :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to following -

```
String myList = obj.get("list").toString();
     list1 = gson.fromJson(myList, collectionType); // delete this not required

     JSONArray obj1 = new JSONArray(list1);
     JSONObject numbersObject = obj1.getJsonObject(0); // change this to get first object from the JsonArray
     String mobileList = 
        numbersObject.get("storeMobileNumbers").toString();
        mobileNumbers = gson.fromJson(mobileList, collection2);
```